# CSS selector based on textbox value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an environment which supports CSS / bootstrap 3.2, - but NO javascript.
I am trying to implement a list filtering solution using pure CSS selector + HTML.

Suppose, I have 2 items in an HTML list element. I want to show only the ones matching the text entered in the input element.

```
<form>
  <ul>
    <li class ="c1">c1</li>
    <li class="c2">c2</li>
  </ul>

  <input type="text">
</form>
```

if I type `c1` in textbox, that should show only the first item.Is this even possible using pure css, no JS?

Comment: bootstrap includes (bootstrap.css, bootstrap.js).. if you are using bootstrap.js then definitely it supports javascript. There is no event handling in css.

Comment: @zingh your needed an event text change but DOM does not provide instant  this, it's possible to use javascript, not possible only CSS + HTML

Answer (score 9):

This is impossible.

- CSS has no means to act based on the current value of an input
- CSS has no means to select an element based on [something that follows it in the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: I was wondering if there are more tricks on the lines of the checkbox hack.. it can effectively control style based on checkbox state.. all in CSS. 
see https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/